# Trouble running go get github.com/go-gl/gl

Tags: go

I get the following error when i run "go get github.com/go-gl/gl"

Im on Windows 7 64bit, i have tried to install MinGW64 and i've tried to install GLEW by doing this:

- bin/glew32.dll       to      %SystemRoot%/system32
- lib/glew32.lib       to      {VC Root}/Lib
- include/GL/glew.h        to      {VC Root}/Include/GL
- include/GL/wglew.h       to      {VC Root}/Include/GL

[image]

PLEASE HELP :<

Comment: You could reopen https://github.com/go-gl/gl/issues/56

Comment: It may be easier for us to help you on the user groups[1], but the short story is that you need to build GLEW from source using the MSYS Makefiles target. Right now you're trying to use Visual C libraries with MinGW and they don't play nicely together. You want a .dll and a .a file, not a .dll and a .lib. [1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/go-gl